# Сократить каждый элемент до 6 знаков после запятой в pandas Series из списков

Tags: python, pandas

Есть Series формата:

```
   coordinates

 0 [53.3727972273301, 83.72454849138683]
 1 [53.339619331, 83.796565491]
 2 [40.3863911233, 49.804998232]
```

Нужно сократить каждый элемент до 6 знаков после точки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Comment: в каком смысле сократить? изменить отображение?

Comment: `s.apply(lambda x: [round(y, 6) for y in x])` ?

Comment: Зачем вам это? Если для отображения, то урезайте именно в момент отображения данные. Хранить и обрабатывать данные лучше с полной точностью.